# Changing the editor in Joomla deleted my javascript, unsaved...Any way to recover?

Tags: javascript, joomla, editor

I used No editor option and joomla and wrote javascript. The code was working perfect. To add other articles I changed editor to TinyMCE, added a table. ...All my javascript is gone, even after I revert back to No editor. Anyway, I can get previous version of article with javascript. Has about 2 days of coding and unfortunately, stupid enough, I don't have back up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way (unfortunately) to get what was saved before and overwritten afterwards.

Two solutions (if it was made after at least one day):

A. Maybe your server was set to backup the database?
If so, you could recover it via the backups.

B. If the site was indexed by Google (and public), try to view a cached version of that page (if accessible and indexed).

Comment: Thanks..Is there any way (except backing up) I can prevent his in future? I will always use No editor option , but may go to some editor by mistake..

Comment: By the way I found the Cache page but that was before my working version

Comment: @user873096 No way to prevent that (sadly), maybe with a versioning system (I think I saw a component that could do that). As for the cached version, try other search engines and even try Google again later and keep an eye on it, with some luck you'll get the correct cached version!

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same issue. To prevent javascript disappearance, just put the javascript tag into html comments. The editor do not delete it and the javascript is still seen in HTML.

```
<!--
  <script language="javascript">
  ...
  </script>
-->
```